# How to tune parameters with a loop?

Tags: python

Here is my current code:

```
filename='training_lr1e-3_rp1e6'

model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-3), loss = 'mse' , metrics = ['mse','mae','mape'])

model.fit(
    x=x_train_z, y=x_train_z,
    validation_data=(x_valid_z,x_valid_z),
    epochs=800, batch_size=50,
    verbose=2,
    callbacks=[logger,history])

model.save(filename+'.h5')
```

I want to run the model with different learning rates and get different outcomes simultaneously, for example, I want to try learning rates: 1e-3 1e-4,...,1e-6 and 2.5e-3,2.5e-4,...,2.5e-6.

How to write a loop to do this work?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: use [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) for the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something like this.

```
lrates = [1e-3, 1e-4]

for lr in lrates:
    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr=lr), loss = 'mse' , metrics = ['mse','mae','mape'])
    
    model.fit(
        x=x_train_z, y=x_train_z,
        validation_data=(x_valid_z,x_valid_z),
        epochs=800, batch_size=50,
        verbose=2,
        callbacks=[logger,history])
    
    model.save('training_lr{}_rp1e6.h5'.format(lr))
```

Though I prefer to define hyperparameters as arguments to the program, and automate them with bash scripts. But you're not asking that. ^^

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your comment! I have thought about the define hyperparameters as arguments, could you also show me a basic idea of how to work on that? Thank you!